# Refresh a variable every second in a blade-template that refreshes a part of the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm using laravel 9 and I'm new to using the blade template view files.

I have a blade template file that shows a table and has some buttons to interact with that.

The table is just a result of `select * from some_table`, and I want it to be refreshed every second, I tried to google.. found broadcasting.. ajax... everything seems a bit too complicated for a simple task as this.

So I have a route at `web.php`

```
Route::get('/test-page', function () {
    return view('test-page');
});
```

and `test-page.blade.php` contains:

```
<?php
  $agents = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('select * from agents');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<table>
...
  <tbody>
     @foreach ($agents as $agent)
       <tr>
        <td>{{ $agent->id }}</td>
        <td> {{ $agent->name }}</td>
...
       </tr>
     @endforeach
```

I want `$agents` variable to be refreshed every second, and the table display would changed accordingly without refreshing the all page. there must be a simple way to do just that.

I guess I can create a route that will return that data in a json format and return it, I'm sure there is a cool Laravel way to resolve this just don't know how or where to start really.

Any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current approach? If you don't want to use AJAX (which would be the best way for this), why not reload the page itself?

Comment: I think Ajax is the simplest solution to your problem. You cannot reload a sub-part of your html without using js(afaik)

Comment: i want to be able to interact with the page while it's reloading it's data

Comment: Then use AJAX for this

Comment: is there a laravel blade way to update specific part of the page with ajax, and how to use ajax with currently configured routes ?

Comment: i need realtime information so yeah every second :)

Comment: ajax can't be use for realtime, use push notification instead

Comment: There is **NOT** simple way for it. You gotta use one of the mentioned methods. And ajax is not the best way (it is easiest). It is better to use broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#introduction) using [Pusher Channels](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels) is the easiest and optimized solution because in case you used AJAX you'll consume many resources you don't need. For instance, if you send a request per second without any data modification it causes a load on the server so, I recommend using **Broadcasting** where we can use event broadcasting to dispatch an event that is received by our application's JavaScript. Once the event is received, we can display the data modification without ever needing to refresh the page.